# Calling parent delegate methods and subclass delegate methods in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates

I am using one library file in my iphone app project. In that library they implemented the uiscrollview delegate method and calling some functions related to the library. I have created a scrollview object and assigned the library class object. When i did scrolling my parent delegate methods calling correctly.

Now, i need to call a custom function(testFunction:) inside my class when one of the scrollview delegate method(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:) is calling. I tried declaring the scrollview delegate in my class but the library delegates are not calling up then!.

Do any one having idea how to call my delegates as well as parent delegate or some other way to get this notified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a method in parent class and override in sub classes. then in delegate method, call this. It will work.

Comment: Thanks shivam for your reply! but actually it is a library file i can't do any change in it as if library going to upgrade then again i need to do this again. Anyhow i will try this but is there any other way?